# About reading data from files to construct setting for application

Tags: android, file

I have a question, I want to ask about reading data from files to construct setting for application.I want to download new files from the server to replace the files in the asset folder, but the files in asset folder doesnt allowed me to replace them, So I want to know is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: You could download files to internal memory or sd card

Answer (score 0):

The assets folder in Android, are readonly, you can't add or edit files. So, if you want to use internal data files and replace them with a download, you have to set another directory, such as Internal Storage or External Storage.